# Why is Trace function in $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ a map $\mathbb{F}_{2^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2$?

Tags: functions, finite-fields

**Except from a paper:**([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaHMXl.jpg))

> A function $F$ from $\mathbb{F}_{2^{n}}$ to $\mathbb{F}_{2^{n}}$ admits a unique representation, called *Univariate Polynomial Representation*, over $\mathbb{F}_{2^{n}}$ of degree at most $2^{n}-1$ :
> $$
> F(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{2^{n}-1} \delta_{j} x^{j}, \text { with } \delta_{j} \in \mathbb{F}_{2^{n}}
> $$
> For every integer $j$ consider its binary expansion $\sum_{s=0}^{n-1} j_{s} 2^{s}$ and denote with $w_{2}(j)$ the number of nonzero coefficients (i.e. $\sum_{s=0}^{n-1} j_{s}$ ). The *algebraic degree* of the function $F$ is the $\max _{j=0, \ldots, 2^{n}-1 / \delta_{j} \neq 0} w_{2}(j)$. Functions of algebraic degree 1 are called *affine* and of degree 2 *quadratic*. *Linear functions* are affine functions without the constant term and they can be represented as $L(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \gamma_{j} x^{2^{j}}$. A known example of a linear function defined over any dimension $n$ is the *Trace function* $\operatorname{Tr}(x)=\operatorname{Tr}_{n}(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^{2^{i}}$, In particular the trace is a Boolean function, i.e. $\operatorname{Tr}: \mathbb{F}_{2^{n}} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{2}$. For $m$ positive divisor of $n$ we use the notation $\operatorname{Tr}^{m}(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n / m-1} x^{2^{i m}}$.

As you can see, in the paper the trace function $Tr$ is $\mathbb{F}_{2^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2$.

Shouldn't it be $\mathbb{F}_{2^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{2^n}\;$? I searched a lot over the internet, but couldn't find an explanation. Please help.

Comment: The trace function maps elements of a field extension to elements of the subfield

Comment: We have, for all $x\in\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$, $Tr(x)^2=Tr(x)$. The elements $y\in\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$ that satisfy $y^2=y$ are precisely the elements of the prime field $\Bbb{F}_2$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor  Did you make that edit using mathpix.com, or can stackexchange do that?

Comment: @311411 the former

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen sorry but I am not a proficient mathematician. It would be great if you could give me an example of a field and specific elements for which I can see that the $Tr(x)^2 = Tr(x)$ property holds.

Comment: All you need is that i) $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$ (because $2xy=0$), and ii) $x^{2^n}=x$ for all $x\in\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. That really helped clear things up